# Buddypress Get xprofile data outside of loop

Tags: wordpress, profile, buddypress

So in buddypress profile fields, I have created two custom fields; First Name, Last Name.
I want to use xprofile_get_field_data to call the first name and the initial of the last name.
Here’s what I have so far
`<?php echo xprofile_get_field_data('field=display name '); ?>`

What else do I need to add to make this happen magically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Outside the loop, you have to provide the user_id

```
xprofile_get_field_data('field=display name', $user_id)
```

How you get the user_id depends on which screen you're using.